# What platform was Google+ rumored to be modeled after?

Tags: open-source, google-plus, social-networking

I remember reading a blog post or something somewhere that said that Google+ either was a modified version of a popular social networking software or was modeled after something of the sort.  I however cannot find this post any longer or anything similar.

At least let me know if anyone sees strong similarities between the platform and another open source platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Diaspora](https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora) seems to have provided inspiration for [Google+](http://plus.google.com), not sure if it goes beyond merely inspiring it.

Comment: That is the one, thanks.  And on a side-note, this is not off topic as the folks who moderated it marked it.  It is an open source platform that I was trying to determine the name of.